# How to shorten a Haskell function definition with many equivalent patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I didn't know how to describe this for the title, but it should be understandable with the example code. How can I shorten this:

```
parse qs (e@Mark        :t@(Noun _)    :Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@Mark        :t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Asgn _)    :t@(Noun _)    :Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Asgn _)    :t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@LeftParen   :t@(Noun _)    :Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@LeftParen   :t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Adv _ _)   :t@(Noun _)    :Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Adv _ _)   :t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Verb _ _ _):t@(Noun _)    :Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Verb _ _ _):t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Noun _)    :t@(Noun _)    :Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
parse qs (e@(Noun _)    :t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = parse qs $ e : f t : ss
```

The list is of type `[Token]` (as is `qs`, which is used in other definitions), which is my own type. Is it possible to have a sub-type of `Token`, covering only `Mark`, `Asgn _`, `LeftParen`, `Adv _ _`, `Verb _ _ _` and `Noun _`, and pattern-match with that?

Edit: definition of `Token`:

```
data Token = (Show, Read a) => Noun a
           | Verb String (Token -> Token) (Token -> Token -> Token)
           | Adv String (Token -> Token) Token
           | Conj String (Token -> Token -> Token) Token
           | Name String
           | Asgn AsgnType
           | Mark
           | LeftParen
           | RightParen
    deriving (Show, Read)
```

Comment: What is the full definition of `Token`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write some helper functions that handle the pattern matches for you (since you don't actually deconstruct the first two elements of the list) and then use guards to check if the patterns are matched.

```
isStartToken :: Token -> Bool
isStartToken = {- returns True for Mark, Asgn, LeftParen etc -}

isNounOrVerb :: Token -> Bool
isNounOrVerb = {- returns True for Noun and Verb only -}

parse qs (e: t: Adv _ f: ss)
    | isStartToken e && isNounOrVerb t = parse qs (e : f t : ss)
    | otherwise                        = {- whatever comes here -}
```

Comment: The `otherwise` case could be a bit difficult, given all my other patterns, but I'll give it a try. I'll mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: Instead of using `otherwise` like this, you can also start a new equation after `parse qs (e : t : Adv _ f : ss) | ... = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a little clearer and shorter:

```
parse qs (e@Mark:ss) = parse qs $ appNounVerbAdv ss
parse qs (e@(Asgn _):ss) = parse qs $ appNounVerbAdv ss
parse qs (e@LeftParen:ss) = parse qs $ appNounVerbAdv  ss
parse qs (e@(Adv _ _) :ss) = parse qs $ appNounVerbAdv ss
parse qs (e@(Verb _ _ _):ss) = parse qs $ appNounVerbAdv  ss
parse qs (e@(Noun _)  :ss) = parse qs $ appNounVerbAdv  ss
...

appNounVerbAdv (t@(Noun _):Adv _ f:ss) = f t : ss
appNounVerbAdv (t@(Verb _ _ _):Adv _ f:ss) = f t : ss
appNounVerbAdv _ = error ""
```

Just try to break your cases up into smaller functions along this pattern whenever you have an argument that isn't used (as in `qs` in `parse` above).

Also maybe a more formal approach like an FSM might help keep things manageable?

Comment: In implementing the previous answer, I've tended towards functions more like your `appNounVerbAdv`. Thanks for confirming that approach.

Comment: On the FSM idea, that could work. I'll bear that in mind, and maybe try to rewrite in that style if this one doesn't work out. My main concern is that my program requires reading against the direction of the input stream. I don't know enough about FSMs to know whether they are suited to that.